# How to override ViewsExposedFilterBlock with my own class?

Tags: views, 8

I want to add an additional form element in the configuration form for `core/modules/views/src/Plugin/Block/ViewsExposedFilterBlock.php` by adding

```
public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);
  $form['my_new_form_element'] = [...];

  return $form;
}
```

If I hack core and add that code in the file, it does what I want. But of course I don't want to hack core. So I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that my custom module's block class is used instead of `ViewsExposedFilterBlock.php`.

So how do I alert Views to use my class, `ExposedFilterImagesBlock.php`?

Information that I've found that might help you help me:

`ViewsExposedFilterBlock.php` has `deriver = "Drupal\views\Plugin\Derivative\ViewsExposedFilterBlock"` in its annotation. So I'm assuming the deriver plays an important role...just one that is unclear to me.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: You don't alert Views. All Views are scanned for configured exposed blocks and a block plugin definition is derived for each one found. You can try to replace the plugin class in hook_block_alter() and check if the derived blocks also have your custom class, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264349/how-do-i-replace-a-plugin/264354#264354

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @4k4 (here) and @nikathone and @dorf (via Slack), I was able to arrive at this, placed in `exposed_filter_images.module` (all caps should be replaced with a machine name):

```
function exposed_filter_images_block_alter(&$plugins) {
  if (isset($plugins['views_exposed_filter_block:VIEW_NAME-DISPLAY_NAME'])) {
    $plugins['views_exposed_filter_block:VIEW_NAME-DISPLAY_NAME']['class'] = \Drupal\exposed_filter_images\Plugin\Block\ExposedFilterImagesBlock::class;
  }
}
```