# Accessing a contrib module's code that has no service

Tags: 8

I am doing custom work on a drupal site that uses particular installation profile. And the profile comes with a huge module that does a lot of work. Some of the classes I've been able to inject into my code.

I understand that interfaces aren't supposed to work this way, but it seems like, inside the module, the interface is passed as a parameter into a class's method and is assigned to a variable and that variable is an object. And from that an object is formed. I know I'm missing something here, I just don't know what.

This is an example of the code in the module:

```
public function userResult(OpignoModuleInterface $opigno_module) {         
$step_info = opigno_learning_path_get_module_step($gid, $uid, 
$opigno_module, $latest_cert_date);       
$current_step_key = array_search($opigno_module->id(), array_column($steps, 'id')); 
}
```

If I run it through Xdebug, $opingo_module is an object. It appears to me that OpignoModuleInterface is assign to $opigno_module. But I'm new to this. It becomes an object. And I really want that object for the custom code I'm creating.

So, this is how I configured my service:

```
    class: Drupal\ptc_after_course_redirect\RouteListener
    arguments: ['']
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

And then I passed the `OpignoModuleInterface` into the class's method just as they had. It didn't work, because there's no service associated with it. As you can see, the `argument` in the yaml file is empty. Nothing to put there.

Per @Clive, it does seem like an entity. Clive recommended this: `$this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('opigno_module')->load($id);`

But it comes back null.

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps.

First you need OOP code to extend classes and override methods and properties. You can of course also rewrite a class from scratch implementing only the interface.

Second you need to implement your new code. If it is not a service which you can swap in the service container it is most times a plugin. Then the plugin manager for each plugin type controls which classes are used. In your case the plugin type is an entity type and its plugin manager is EntityTypeManager which provides a hook hook_entity_type_alter() to replace the existing module code with your extended classes.

See [How do I replace a plugin?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264349/how-do-i-replace-a-plugin)

This is how to access class code of contrib modules. How these classes are instantiated is a different matter and there is no general answer, because some classes are when Drupal is bootstrapped, other only when a certain functionality is used. But by replacing the class code with your own you can be sure that your blueprint is used to create these instances.