# How to override a class method that is not a service?

Tags: 8, views

Usually we override services using RouteSubscribers, but i need to override a method of a class that is not a service.
I need to alter the module of the core "views", the general structure of this module is:

```
> views
  > src
    > Entity
      > Render
        - ConfigurableLanguageRenderer.php
        - EntityTranslationRenderTrait.php
```

I need to override one method of one of those files.

In ConfigurableLanguageRenderer.php i need to override "getLanguage()" method
or in EntityTranslationRenderTrait.php i need to override "getEntityTranslation()" method, but i don't know how override a trait or a class that is not a service, is that possible? Thanks.

**--- More context ---**

A hook_language_fallback_candidates_OPERATION_alter() was implemented and we have a custom priority candidates to return the content translated, but one validation in the views module broke my custom fallback candidates.

**E.G:** if the content was written in English(en), and you send in the view rest the parameter lang=en, the view will be skip to search the translation in the candidates and the hook_language_fallback... doesn't be executed because if you looking for a node in english and this article has english as default is not necessary to search translation and this return the original language of the content.

Then i need to alter the langcode that return `$this->getEntityTranslationRenderer()->getLangcode($row)`

- ConfigurableLanguageRenderer.php

  ```
  public function getEntityTranslation(EntityInterface $entity, ResultRow $row) {
    // We assume the same language should be used for all entity fields
    // belonging to a single row, even if they are attached to different entity
    // types. Below we apply language fallback to ensure a valid value is always
    // picked.
    $translation = $entity;
    if ($entity instanceof TranslatableInterface && count($entity->getTranslationLanguages()) > 1) {
      $langcode = $this->getEntityTranslationRenderer()->getLangcode($row);
      $translation = $this->getEntityRepository()->getTranslationFromContext($entity, $langcode);
    }
    return $translation;
  }
  ```

So i need to alter those methods or alter the default language of the node, or if it's possible alter "context" to enter to the following validation: `($entity->language()->getId() != $langcode)`

```
public function getTranslationFromContext(EntityInterface $entity, $langcode = NULL, $context = []) {
    $translation = $entity;

    if ($entity instanceof TranslatableDataInterface && count($entity->getTranslationLanguages()) > 1) {
      if (empty($langcode)) {
        $langcode = $this->languageManager->getCurrentLanguage(LanguageInterface::TYPE_CONTENT)->getId();
        $entity->addCacheContexts(['languages:' . LanguageInterface::TYPE_CONTENT]);
      }

      // Retrieve language fallback candidates to perform the entity language
      // negotiation, unless the current translation is already the desired one.
      if ($entity->language()->getId() != $langcode) {
        $context['data'] = $entity;
        $context += ['operation' => 'entity_view', 'langcode' => $langcode];
        $candidates = $this->languageManager->getFallbackCandidates($context);

        // Ensure the default language has the proper language code.
        $default_language = $entity->getUntranslated()->language();
        $candidates[$default_language->getId()] = LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_DEFAULT;

        // Return the most fitting entity translation.
        foreach ($candidates as $candidate) {
          if ($entity->hasTranslation($candidate)) {
            $translation = $entity->getTranslation($candidate);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return $translation;
  }
```

**-- Update --**

as @4k4 mentioned i overwritten the service EntityRepository.php and that solved my problem

```
class GlobalizationServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase {

  /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    if ($container->hasDefinition('entity.repository')) {
      $definition = $container->getDefinition('entity.repository');
      $definition->setClass('Drupal\Globalization\CustomEntityRepository');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to provide a bit of context as to what you're trying to achieve. There might be other ways to achieve what you're trying to do than this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first class is hard coded in the second class and the second class is a trait used in different field and row plugins. So you need to target one of those plugins. There are several ways. The preferred one is to assign a custom plugin ID to the extended plugin class and configure it in your custom View. If you want to override the plugin class in general see [How do I replace a plugin?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264349/how-do-i-replace-a-plugin)

---

The last method you've added in **more context** is in a service and you can implement `MyEntityRepository::getTranslationFromContext()` and then swap the class in a ServiceProvider (not RouteSubcriber): See [altering existing services](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic).

Comment: as @4k4 that was the solution to my problem, thanks