# How can I extend an existing View display style?

Tags: views

I'm using the [views_summarize](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_summarize) module, which adds a custom View display style. The display style is basically a Table view but it allows you to display a summary of a column in a row at the bottom of the table in a variety of formats you can choose from.

[image: Views summarize formats]

I need to add a custom format to this list and in the Drupal 7 version of the module this could be done with hooks ([see here](https://github.com/backdrop-contrib/views_summarize#extending)). But since it was updated for Drupal 8/9 I can't figure out how to extend the [display style plugin](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/views_summarize/-/blob/1.1.x/src/Plugin/views/style/TableSummarized.php) or if it's even possible.

I would ask the module developers but I don't think they've touched the module in a couple years, hoping someone can point me in the right direction here. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extending the plugin class

*/mymodule/src/Plugin/views/style/MyTableSummarized.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\views\style;

use Drupal\views_summarize\Plugin\views\style\TableSummarized;

class MyTableSummarized extends TableSummarized {

  protected function getHandlers() {
    $handlers = parent::getHandlers();
    // add your own handler
    $handlers['bar'] = 'Bar';
    return $handlers;
  }

}
```

you can replace the class in the plugin manager:

*/mymodule/mymodule.module*

```
function mymodule_views_plugins_style_alter(array &$info) {
  if (isset($info['tablesummarized'])) {
    $info['tablesummarized']['class'] = '\Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\views\style\MyTableSummarized';
  }
}
```

See [How do I replace a plugin?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264349/how-do-i-replace-a-plugin)

Comment: Perfect, thank you!